# Recursive way to find inorder successor

Tags: c, recursion, tree

So far I have attempted to find the inorder successor through recursion and it seems to be working right. Can someone review the code and give suggestions?

```
struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node* left;
    struct node* right;
};

struct node * inOrderSuccessor(struct node *root, struct node *n)
{
    if(root == NULL)
        return NULL;

    static node *successor = NULL;
    if(root->data >= n->data)
    {
        successor = root;
        successor->data = root->data;
    }

    if(root->right !=NULL && n->data >= root->data)
        return inOrderSuccessor(root->right,n);

    if(root->left != NULL && n->data < root->data)
        return inOrderSuccessor(root->left ,n);

    return successor;
}

    struct node* newNode(int data)
    {
        struct node* node = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        node->data   = data;
        node->left   = NULL;
        node->right  = NULL;

        return(node);
    }

    int main()
    {
        struct node *temp, *succ,*successor=NULL;
        struct node *root = newNode(20);
        root->left        = newNode(8);
        root->left->left  = newNode(4);
        root->right       = newNode(22);
        root->left->right = newNode(12);
        root->left->right->left=newNode(10);
        root->left->right->right=newNode(14);


        temp = root->left->left;

        succ =  inOrderSuccessor(root, temp);
        if(succ !=  NULL)
            printf("\n Inorder Successor of %d is %d ", temp->data, succ->data);   
        else
            printf("\n Inorder Successor doesn't exit");

        getchar();
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Does it work for a tree with these nodes: 16, 12, 10, 8, 11 ? Inorder successor of 11 seems to return 11, but should return 12.

Comment: Does "working right" mean that it should report "_Inorder Successor of 4 is 4_"?  I would expect the correct result to be __8__.

Answer (score 1):

There is not a sufficient level of testing of the function. It would be better to have multiple test cases to test the function. This question would also be more interesting if the code to build the tree was included.

**BUG**
The code does not test the existence of the node pointer `n` accessing through the pointer, this can result in undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

We're missing includes of `<stdio.h>` and `<stdlib.h>`.

The use of static local `successor` in the recursive function makes it hard to reason about, and also prevents the function being used in a thread-safe manner - prefer to pass that between invocations as necessary.  I'm assuming that its type should be `struct node` rather than `node` - this makes it look like you have presented code you've not even compiled!

The assignment `successor->data = root->data` achieves nothing when `successor` and `root` point at the same node.  Remove this, and then the function can accept `struct node const*` as users would expect (a search should not be modifying the tree!).

On the subject of the function's arguments, the only thing we use from `n` is its `data`, so consider passing just the value so the caller doesn't need a `struct node` for this.

The logic is incorrect - when I run it, I always get the passed-in node as result, rather than its successor.

---

We needn't (and IMO shouldn't) cast the `void*` returned by `malloc()`.  And it's good practice to use `sizeof` on the assigned-to object rather than requiring the reviewer to check that its type matches that being measured:

```
    struct node *node = malloc(sizeof *node);
```

If `malloc()` cannot allocate memory and therefore returns a null pointer, we immediately run into Undefined Behaviour by dereferencing it (`node->data`).

No need for extra parens around `node` when returning it.

---

The `main()` function declares `successor` but never uses it.  And prefer to declare variables when we have values to initialise them with (as we do for `root`).

```
    struct node *root = newNode(20);
    ⋮
    struct node *temp = root->left->left;
    struct node *succ =  inOrderSuccessor(root, temp);
```

Prefer to print whole lines of output (i.e. ending in newline).  Unterminated lines are a nuisance (typically they confuse the shell about column position for the next command).

Typo in the message - that should say "doesn't **exist**".

What's that `getchar()` doing there?  We don't need any input, and we seem to ignore what we read, so just remove that.

Returning a zero value from `main()` (but no other function) is optional, so no need to write that last line.

We may want to release the memory we allocated (certainly in Valgrind runs, to make it easier to detect memory leaks).

---

## Improved code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node* left;
    struct node* right;
};

struct node const *inOrderSuccessor(struct node const *root, int value)
{
    if (!root) {
        return root;
    }

    if (value < root->data) {
        struct node const *p = inOrderSuccessor(root->left, value);
        return p ? p : root;
    } else {
        return inOrderSuccessor(root->right, value);
    }
}

struct node* newNode(int data)
{
    struct node *node = malloc(sizeof *node);
    if (node) {
        node->data   = data;
        node->left   = NULL;
        node->right  = NULL;
    }

    return node;
}

struct node const *insert(struct node *root, int data)
{
    struct node **p = &root;
    struct node *const n = newNode(data);
    if (!n) {
        return n;
    }

    while (*p) {
        if (data < (*p)->data) {
            p = &(*p)->left;
        } else {
            p = &(*p)->right;
        }
    }
    return *p = n;
}

void freeTree(struct node *root)
{
    if (root) {
        freeTree(root->left);
        freeTree(root->right);
    }
    free(root);
}


int main(void)
{
    struct node *root = newNode(20);
    if (!insert(root, 8)
        || !insert(root, 4)
        || !insert(root, 22)
        || !insert(root, 12)
        || !insert(root, 10)
        || !insert(root, 14)) {
        fputs("Failed to create the tree\n", stderr);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    int searchVal = 10;
    struct node const *succ =  inOrderSuccessor(root, searchVal);
    if (succ) {
        printf("Inorder Successor of %d is %d\n", searchVal, succ->data);
    } else {
        printf("Inorder Successor doesn't exist\n");
    }

    freeTree(root);
}
```